# Maya connecting two edges

Tags: maya

Using Maya right now

I can't find a good way to fix this.

I want to make a new face here, to repalce the missing face.

how can I make an edge between the selected edges?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbPHN.png]

Comment: Would Mesh > Fill Hole not do the trick? Then just subdivide it and move the vertexes into place.

Answer (score 0):

While there are plenty of ways to go about this. What I typically do is just extrude the edges out, then manually connect the vertices. Once you have one connected, then you can use say, fill hole to connect the other.

So, to recap.

- Extrude an edge
- Move it in place
- Manually connect the vertices
- Then fill the hole

Hope that helps :D